# event.params.wildcard returning the wrong value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a pretty simple firebase function :

```
exports.sendFollowNotification = functions.database.ref('PendingRequest/{receiver_id}/{sender_id}').onWrite(requestEvent => {
    const requestSnapShot = requestEvent.data;
    const senderId = requestEvent.params.sender_id;
    const targetId = requestEvent.params.receiver_id;

    const target_token = requestSnapShot.child('sender').val();
    const sender_token = requestSnapShot.child('receiver').val();
    console.log('sender_id :'+senderId);
    console.log('target_id :'+targetId); 
    console.log('target_token: '+ target_token);
    console.log('sender_token: '+sender_token);

    const pendingRequestPayload = {
        data: {
            token_sender : sender_token,
            token_target : target_token,
            request_sender : senderId,
            request_receiver : targetId,                
            my_message_id: '0'
        }
    };

    if(target_token != null){   

     // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(target_token, pendingRequestPayload)
        .then(function (response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
            // contents of response.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

    }
```

Whenever this function fires there are two values that gets swapped : senderId gets targetId value and vice versa. Both values are retrieved with the params property while nothing strange happens to the values i'm getting from requestSnapShot.child('value_name').val();
The dumb solution is just to swap the two values whenever i need them but well, that's a really dumb solution. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Exactly. I accidentally pasted the "dumb workaround"...i mean, it totally works swapping the 2 values and i could just leave the code on tjis way but it doesn't really make any sense

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If "target" is "receiver", these are swapped:

```
const target_token = requestSnapShot.child('sender').val();
const sender_token = requestSnapShot.child('receiver').val();
```

Are you doing that intentionally to work around the problem?

**Update:**

It's hard to guess why this isn't working for you. I copied your code, eliminated your work-around, and shortened it for testing:

```
exports.sendFollowNotification = functions.database.ref('PendingRequest/{receiver_id}/{sender_id}')
       .onWrite(requestEvent => {
    const requestSnapShot = requestEvent.data;
    const senderId = requestEvent.params.sender_id;
    const targetId = requestEvent.params.receiver_id;

    const target_token = requestSnapShot.child('receiver').val();
    const sender_token = requestSnapShot.child('sender').val();
    console.log('sender_id :'+senderId);
    console.log('target_id :'+targetId);
    console.log('target_token: '+ target_token);
    console.log('sender_token: '+sender_token);
});
```

Ran with this data:

```
{
  "PendingRequest" : {
    "R1" : {
      "S1" : {
        "receiver" : "R-token",
        "sender" : "S-token"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And got this log output:

```
sender_token: S-token
target_token: R-token
target_id :R1
sender_id :S1
```

Comment: I'm honestly really puzzled aswell, Instead of swapping those value i'm now just adding 2 more childs under sender_id to store senderId and receiverId and then just get em with child().val() and everything works just fine. But i'm still writing/reading repeting data into my database